# Modify inner classes

Tags: java, inner-classes, java-bytecode-asm

I modified a method in an inner class but the problem is to it doesn't get written. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with it.

```
private void transformPortal(ClassNode classNode) {
    for (InnerClassNode innerClassNode : classNode.innerClasses) {
        if (!innerClassNode.name.equals(getName("BlockPortal$Size").get()))
            continue;
        try {
            ClassNode classNode1 = new ClassNode();
            ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(innerClassNode.name);
            classReader.accept(classNode1, 0);

            for (MethodNode method : classNode1.methods) {

                if (method.name.equals(getName("isValid").get())) {
                    for (AbstractInsnNode node : method.instructions.toArray()) {
                        if (node.getOpcode() == IRETURN) {
                            method.instructions.insertBefore(node, new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, HOOKS, "isValid", "()Z", false));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
            classNode1.accept(classWriter);
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This all works when I run it but the problem is to class writer isn't writing it so nothing gets changed.
This is where I call that method:

```
try {
        ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(clazz);
        classReader.accept(classNode, 0);

        transformPortal(classNode);

        ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        classNode.accept(classWriter);
        return classWriter.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

I also tried setting the InnerClassNode after modifying it in the classNode.innerClasses List but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, forgot to that class only starts when I try to do the thing that starts it. It now works if I try to get the `BlockPortal$Size` straight away instead of `BlockPortal` and then `Size`.